# Is password age cached locally, along with login?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, credentials

We have a number of users that work remotely (off-domain), and before I set the password age (and complexity) on our AD, I wondered if the password age is stored locally, along with the login data. The last thing I want is to bugger up anything for our remote users.

I can't find anything that suggests it does cache this locally (it really wouldn't make sense in my mind), but equally I can't find anything that suggests it doesn't.

Can anyone state the position categorically for me?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm through experience (working disconnected from domain) that the expiration doesn't affect the cached credentials.

Basically when the password would expire, I'd have to enter the new one into e.g Outlook or OWA, but when logging into Windows on the laptop, I would use the old (expired) password.

Note that even if you can log in to Windows itself, certain apps can have trouble with expired passwords.  Outlook prompts, however other apps may not.  For example, SSRS stops working once the password expires, because the hosting app just passes through the (expired) Windows credentials with no subsequent prompt if they don't work.

Comment: Password age has nothing to do with the expiration of an old password. It just prevents users from changing passwords quickly so they can use old ones (must be x days old to change password).

Comment: @Mark: You are absolutely correct in that it isn't cached, contrary to what I stated in my answer. I checked it out proper: http://blogs.technet.com/b/jesper_johansson/archive/2006/04/21/425991.aspx I have simply assumed that my remote users which get locked out (regular support calls) have expired passwords. Leaves me to figure out what actually happens, which is a good outcome of the misconception I had.

Comment: @Nathan: You are referring to the minimum password age policy setting. There is also a maximum password age policy setting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change your password when disconnected from the network, so there's no purpose of storing this password age locally. If a user attempted to change their password, they would be greeted with an error since it has to contact a domain controller to perform the change.

Further, there's no actual object in active directory with the "max age" as it's global, so that further points to it not being stored locally in any way.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]: This answer is based on a misconception. See Mark Sowuls answer instead.

If you set password age in the domain policy, connect a computer such that it picks up the policy, change password on the logged on user and take the computer off site, you will find the password expires after the duration. It will still give the usual password expiry notice.

You will still be able to change the password locally, it will then come out of sync with the domain account whose password will expire.

This can (mostly) be mitigated by logging on to a domain connected terminal server through vpn and changing the domain user password to whatever you set it to on the local computer (before expiry)

Or ask the user to visit the office network for a proper sync, which they often will fail to do in time :-)

Proper user education is key to minimizing the support calls for this.

Comment: Password age has nothing to do with the expiration of an old password. It just prevents users from changing passwords quickly so they can use old ones (must be x days old to change password).

Comment: You are referring to the minimum password age policy setting. I'm referring to the maximum password age policy setting. They both exist.